# How can I control the key with IzPack class?

Tags: izpack

I'm trying to control the product key with IzPack. I did it with RegularExpressionClass but, I should write my own class to control lots of key.
I use it as below, but I can not do the same thing with the class.

```
<userInput>
    <panel id="keyControl">
        <field type="rule" align="left" variable="the.password">
        <spec txt="the key:"
        layout=" O:6:6 "/>
            <validator class="com.j32bit.installer.validator.RegularExpressionValidator" txt="wrong key!!" id="lang pack key for the error text">
                <param name="pattern" value="asd"/>
            </validator>
        </field>
    </panel>
</userInput>
```

I hope, my explanation is understandable. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the message by overriding getErrorMessageId method with your validator class:

```
@Override
public String getErrorMessageId()
{
  return "Your.error.message";
}
```

Where *Your.error.message* points to the particular key from CustomLangPack XML file(s):

```
<str id="Your.error.message" txt="Enter text here" />
```